# PostgreSQL: Execute queries in loop - performance issues

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql

I need to copy data from a file into a PostgreSQL database. For that purpose I parse that file using bash in a loop and generate the corresponding insert queries. The trouble is that it takes a lot of time in order to perform that loop.

1)What can I do to accelerate that loop? Should I open a kind of connection before the loop and close it after?

2)Should I use a temporary text file inside the loop in order to write there the unique values and search in it using the text utility instead of writing them to the database and perform a search there?

Answer (score 1):

Does whatever programming language you use commit after every insert? If so, the easiest thing you can do is commit after inserting all rows rather than after every row.

You might also be able to batch inserts, but using the PostgreSQL [copy](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-copy.html) command is less work and also very fast.

Comment: I use bash. Does it matter?

Comment: bash doesn't talk to Postgres, at least not as far as I know. Are you calling psql from your bash script? Is the loop in your bash script? If so, then you're also adding overhead to connect and disconnect to the database for each row in the file. `copy` command is probably the way to go, will be worth the effort, even if you need to process the file to get it into an acceptable format.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using BASH you could split files by defined row numbers and then excecute paralel commands using `&` at the end of each line.

I strongly suggest you try a different approach or programing language since as Bill said, bash doesn't talk to postgres, you can also use the pg_dump funtionality if your file's source is another postgres database.